# Vertical output from FreeTDS fisql

Tags: sql-server, unix, freetds

With the mysql shell, you can get vertical output when executing interactive queries by ending them with `\G` instead of `;`.

For example:

```
mysql> select * from foo limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      sid: foo
    login: bar
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is it possible to do the same using `fisql` from [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/)?

Alternatively, I will accept an answer that can recommend a better UNIX-compatible command line interface to SQL Server that has this capability.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered [sqsh](http://www.sqsh.org) which seems to do the trick:

```
$ sqsh -S server:1433 -U sa  
sqsh-2.1 Copyright (C) 1995-2001 Scott C. Gray
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
For more information type '\warranty'
Password: 
1> select * from sys.databases where name = 'master'
2> go -m vert
name:                           master
database_id:                    1
source_database_id:             NULL
owner_sid:                      0x01
...

(1 row affected)
```